# Facebook Comments in iOS with loadHTMLstring

Tags: javascript, objective-c, ios, facebook, uiwebview

I have problem with Facebook Comments plugin. Is it event possible to embed it on UIWebView in iOS application? I don't mean using loadUrl method ... but using loadHTMLstring ( I want it only localy on my application, without using any messy obj-c code if it's possible ). I'm using HTML5 code for it, but it's not working on simulator ...

Am I doing anything wrong?

I've read similar topics, but haven't found any solution, that might help me.

Thank's in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

well, i found some workaround for this problem. what i needed is to load local html page with comments plugin embedded. this html page is stored in resources of project. so the code for me was something like that:

```
    [reviewsView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"comments" withExtension:@"html"]]];
```

where `reviewsView` is a UIWebView element. however, it didn't work correctly in the end - comments had loaded, but facebook "loading progress bar" was still animating and for some reason login button was unclickable. so i just returned to the idea with remote html comments page.